# What is the difference between "restart" and "update and restart" in Microsoft Windows 10 1809? Choosing "restart" installs updates anyway

Tags: windows-10, reboot

What is the difference between "restart" and "update and restart" in Microsoft Windows 10 1809 (a.k.a. Redstone 5 and October 2018)? Choosing "restart" installs updates anyway, so I wonder if there is any difference.

[image: Microsoft Windows 10's start menu]

Updates after choosing "restart":

[image]

Comment: Restart use to work without installing updates, but Windows 10 changes things with every new release. I dont see in your case there is any difference.